# Why can't I see the data query account in the accounts section?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, user-accounts

When I go to [my accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/1327442/?tab=accounts) page I can't find the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/10273) account.

What makes this site more special than the others? Why doesn't it appear in the list of accounts?

Comment: Because data explorer is special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Explorer does not really belong to Stack Exchange network of sites.

It was created by a former Stack Exchange employee [Sam Saffron](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) to be used as "a web tool for sharing, querying, and analyzing the Creative Commons data from every website in the Stack Exchange network".

[Source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/).

Only sites with the following on top are official members in the network:

[image]

(The design might still change across sites, but that's its general look)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the data explorer isn't part of the SE network's authentication:

> **I already have a Stack Exchange account, why am I jon.doe#### here?**
>
> Data Explorer doesn't participate in the Stack Exchange network authentication scheme, so your account here is completely separate. Don't worry though, you can update your name in your profile at any time! -- [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)